# Ireport to CSV is appending an Â to all currency cells

Tags: jasper-reports

It seems when I run my report and export it to `Excel` `.CSV` all my currency values seem to append an `Â` at the beginning.

My `XML` is as follows:

```
</textField>
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="£ #,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement x="760" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="cba1b317-f85f-4b3b-9549-66389c451cfa"/>
    <textElement>
        <font size="10" pdfEncoding="Cp1252"/>
    </textElement>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ItemRateBilled}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

I've changed the pattern numerous times to no avail. It seems the following is the issue however, I can't figure out how to resolve:

> The pound symbol is Unicode `codepoint 163`. If it's written to a `UTF-8` encoded file, it's written as the sequence 194, 163. When the file is imported in Excel, a different encoding is assumed, probably the default ANSI code page. Therefore, the sequence 194, 163 is not interpreted as one Unicode `codepoint`. Instead, it's interpreted as the sequence `Â` and `£`.
>
> So, either make `Excel` interpret the file as a `UTF-8` encoded file, or write the file yourself by specifying the `System.Text.Encoding.Default codepage.`

Current error as a CSV:

[image: CSV issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue originating from Jasper but from Excel.

If you take a look into the file with a program able to interpret UTF-8 (like Notepad++), this should not happen at all.

CSV files exported from Jasper should not be opened directly. Instead, Excel should be opened and in the data tab the *import from file* function should be used.

When importing the CSV file, change the input encoding to UTF-8. Then Excel will interpret the file correctly.